# Execute SP with another SP from linked DB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec

I tried to execute Stored Procedure(SP) with another SP from linked DB code worked smoothly there was no error, but it doesn't insert data my table.

Here is the code of Stored Procedure

```
USE [MYDB] 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYDB_SP] 
@ReportDate         smalldatetime ='19000101'
AS
IF(@ReportDate = '19000101')
SELECT @ReportDate = convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112)

BEGIN
SELECT * 
INTO #MYDBTABLETMP
FROM MYDBTABLE 

INSERT INTO #MYDBTABLETMP       
   ([DATAAREAID]
   ,[REPORTDATE]
   ,[ACCOUNTNUM]       
   ,[NAME]
   ,[CUSTGROUP]
   ,[CURRENCYCODE]
   ,[TOTAL])
((select SPTABLE.[DATAAREAID] 
,SPTABLE.[REPORTDATE]
   ,SPTABLE.[ACCOUNTNUM]
   ,SPTABLE.[NAME]
   ,SPTABLE.[CUSTGROUP]
   ,SPTABLE.[CURRENCYCODE]
   ,SPTABLE.[TOTAL]    
   FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','LINKEDSERVER'; 'USERNAM' ; 'PASSWORD' ,
'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; exec LINKEDDB.LINKEDDB_SP 1,''20161201'' ') as SPTABLE))

delete MYDBTABLE where DATAAREAID = 'AAA'

INSERT INTO MYDBTABLE 
SELECT * FROM #MYDBTABLETMP WHERE DATAAREAID = 'AAA'

DROP TABLE #ERPCUSTAGINGTMP 
END
```

Comment: Have you checked contents of `#MYDBTABLETMP` after insert from linked sp? Does it have necessary data?

Answer (score 0):

Try insert *this* into procedure (=between BEGIN and END):

```
IF(@ReportDate = '19000101')
SELECT @ReportDate = convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Now your script doesn't reach begin. And create only first statement set as your procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MYDB_SP] 
@ReportDate         smalldatetime ='19000101'
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@ReportDate = '19000101')
         SELECT @ReportDate = convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112)
    ...
END
```